# Do Esperanto audio recordings with English translations exist?

Tags: resource-request, esperanto

Do you know about any Esperanto audio recordings with English translation?

By audio recordings I do not mean language lessons. I would like something more like audio versions of journal/magazine articles or books. If there is nothing with English translations, it would be enough to have the content of the audio transcribed in Esperanto. The recordings do not have to be too long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if this is enough for you, but [Librivox](https://librivox.org/search?primary_key=20&search_category=language&search_page=1&search_form=get_results) has a few recording in Esperanto that are public domain. The Esperanto transcript can be found under "Links" in the sidebar by clicking on "Online text" or clicking "Etext" under the "Source" header. Most of the non-language learning recordings are books or documents that have English counterparts freely available online in public domain.

Answer (score 10):

Do YouTube Videos count? [Evildea](https://www.youtube.com/c/evildela/featured)'s YouTube channel is largely spoken in Esperanto and subtitled in Esperanto and English. Most of the sub-title work is done through the Amara.org site ([example](http://amara.org/eo/videos/xSS7Fns4lu9M/info/evildea-should-not-be-a-teacher-evildea-devus-ne-esti-instruisto/)).

Answer (score 9):

[LoyalBooks](http://www.loyalbooks.com/language/Esperanto?sort=alphabet) also has four Esperanto audiobooks: [Dr. Esperanto's International Language, Introduction and Complete Grammar](http://www.loyalbooks.com/book/dr-esperantos-international-language-introduction-and-complete-grammar-by-ll-zamenhof) (original book that introduced Esperanto), [Esperanto Self-Taught with Phonetic Pronunciation](http://www.loyalbooks.com/book/Esperanto-Self-Taught-with-Phonetic-Pronunciation-1) (Esperanto grammar book), [La Aventuroj de Alicio en Mirlando](http://www.loyalbooks.com/book/Aventuroj-de-Alicio-en-Mirlando) (Alice in Wonderland translated into Esperanto), and [Fabeloj](http://www.loyalbooks.com/book/Fabeloj-de-Andersen-by-H-C-Andersen) (short stories translated into Esperanto). English translations aren't included, but a quick search for them on the Internet will suffice to find them.

Comment: LoyalBooks is excellent resource for **so many** languages. Thank you! Books should be free :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a link to the Tatoeba Project that will show you community-contributed Esperanto sentences with audio and English translations:

https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query=&from=epo&to=eng&orphans=no&unapproved=no&user=&tags=&has_audio=yes&trans_filter=limit&trans_to=eng&trans_link=&trans_user=&trans_orphan=&trans_unapproved=&trans_has_audio=&sort=words

That will show you the shortest sentences first, but you can change the options by using the right-hand side of the page.

Click on the loudspeaker icon to hear the audio for a sentence.

Answer (score 7):

Amara has more than 300 videos in English with transcript in Esperanto.

Here is the direct link:
[Amara On Demand](http://www.amara.org/en/search/#/?q=&video_lang=en&langs=eo).

As Chad Walstrom said, I recommend to look for the videos of Evildea, since they cover everyday use of Esperanto, and a huge lot has transcripts.

Comment: Amara also has almost 200 videos in Esperanto with transcripts in Esperanto: http://www.amara.org/en/search/#/?q=&video_lang=eo&langs=eo as well as in Esperanto with transcripts in English: http://www.amara.org/en/search/#/?q=&video_lang=eo&langs=en

Answer (score 5):

Something I've used for Japanese is [RhinoSpike](https://rhinospike.com/). I think the most popular way is to submit text in the target language and request an audio recording of the text. You can also request transcriptions of video or audio of the target language.

Some video and audio resources you might like. First there's [Farbskatol'](http://farbskatol.esperanto-jeunes.org/) which I don't think is active now but the archive is online. There's also Chinese Radio International in Esperanto online. Audio recordings usually have transcriptions in Esperanto. I can only add two links at the moment but look for interviews. They're short and you will be treated to a mix of speakers, genders and accents.